# How to build a multifile c++ project for llvm (lli) using clang++?

Tags: makefile, llvm, clang

I have a multifile c++ project, built with help of Makefile. `CC` and `CXX` were `gcc` and `g++` relatively. Now I need to try this project under llvm (lli).
I have replaced

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
LD = ld
```

with

```
CC = clang
CXX = clang++
LD = clang++
```

and added `-emit-llvm` to cflags:

```
CFLAGS_DEBUG =  $(CFLAGS) -g -emit-llvm
...
CFLAGS_RELEASE =  $(CFLAGS) -O2 -emit-llvm
```

Then I invoked make. Object files were built, but while collecting them into application, I got this error:

> obj/Debug/../../XX/YY.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So, how I must build this project properly for the LLVM runtime interpreter (lli)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should link via llvm-link, not via clang++